# Insert Additional Table Rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm attempting to insert additional table rows into a table specifically for mobile devices so that all table data cells show in a list. So for example the layout is currently 2x2 layout but I want this to show as 1x4.

The code I have below is correct for the function because I can replace `</tr><tr>` with example text and this will then show. The issue is that when I remove text and put `</tr><tr>`, it isn't taking effect and I can't see it within the source code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".desctable").find('td:nth-child(even)').append("</tr><tr>");;
});
```

```html
<table class="desctable">
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 1</td>
    <td>Table Data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 3</td>
    <td>Table Data 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So basically I need the front-end result to be this:

```html
<table class="desctable">
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Could anybody please advise why this isn't working? Thank you very much for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `append()` method can only insert elements or text nodes into the DOM. `</tr><tr>` is not an element or a text node.

Instead, you could insert a row after each existing row, using `append()` to move the last cell of the previous row to the new row:

```js
$('.desctable tr').each(function() {
  $('<tr>')                          //Create new row.
    .append($(this).find('td:last')) //Add the last cell of the current row to it.
    .insertAfter($(this));           //Place it after the current row.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="desctable">
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 1</td>
    <td>Table Data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 3</td>
    <td>Table Data 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just also wrong :) (i mean your text with "not HTML code"

Comment: Actually, you make a very good point.  I've edited my explanation.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. It's a weird answer anyway. `append` for sure make real DOM elements out of it, but a DOM element is represented with an HTML code, so...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest using a responsive CSS framework to format things for different screen sizes.

Skeleton CSS is very simple:
http://getskeleton.com

Everyone in the world uses Bootstrap:
http://getskeleton.com

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show some rows only in mobile and if you use bootstrap, check this. change your browser size and see result.

```
<table class="desctable table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 1</td>
    <td>Table Data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data 3</td>
    <td>Table Data 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
    <td>Only mobile</td>
    <td>Only mobile</td>
  </tr>
</table>

http://codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/MyBzyw
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!